# Rails nested group and count with column renaming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model which looks this way:

```
Issue(id, ..., tracker_id)
                   |
          Tracker(id, ..., name)
```

---

```
Issue has_one :tracker
Tracker has_many :issues
```

And I would like to get the number of Issues per Tracker. What I have got is:

```
Issue.group(:tracker_id).count => {3=>446, 5=>247, 9=>2, 11=>560}
```

But instead of grouping by `tracker_id`, I would like to group by `tracker_name`, to get this:

```
{"name_1"=>446, "name_2"=>247, "name_3"=>2, "another_name"=>560}
```

Is there a way to do this directly, without any mapping operation / hash renaming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way:

```
Issue.joins(:tracker).group('trackers.name').count
```